# Why the time complexity of the most unefficient failure function in KMP algorithm is O(n³)? - edited

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

Oh, sorry about my explanation. Actually, I'm learning algorithm with my textbook, and now I 'm looking KMP algorithm. And in textbook, there are two ways to get failure function value. One is most efficient one as you said, O(n), and another one is the most unefficient one as I said above O(n³). Plus, there is no code in my book for O(n³) idea. Instead, the textbook says, "we can check all poossible prefix-suffix pair. If there is pattern P[1,.i], there is possible pair of i-1, and the time complexity is proportional to length, so (i-1) + (i-2)...+1 = i*(i-1)/2. So for all i, O(n³) is trivial ?

So my question is this. I can't understand the explanation in my textbook. Can you explain it???

Comment: I assume you are missing the O(n) for string traversal. If not, please explain your understanding (+ some code or pseudocode) and we can have a look.

Comment: Oh, sorry about my explanation. Actually, I'm learning algorithm with my textbook, and now I 'm looking KMP algorithm. And in textbook, there are two ways to get failure function value. One is most efficient one as you said, O(n), and another one is the most unefficient one as I said above O(n³). Plus, there is no code in my book for O(n³) idea. Instead, the textbook says, "we can check all poossible prefix-suffix pair. If there is pattern P[1,.i], there is possible pair of i-1, and the time complexity is proportional to length, so (i-1) + (i-2)...+1 = i*(i-1)/2. So for all i, O(n³) is trivial

Comment: There is always a way to do worse. But doing O(n³) with KMP... (n chars)? Maybe the book is talking about a trivial search, not KMP, that takes O(n³)? Any reference to the textbook?